# Two way synchronization of Gerrit Server and remote Git Server

Tags: git, devops

I am trying to synchronize the two git-repositories Gerrit Server and Git remote server.  I use git --mirror to sync Gerrit Server with Git remote server. But at the same time i want  to be in sync with Gerrit Server. So that if i will push some changes in Gerrit Server that should be reflected in Git remote server like wise if the some change happens in Git remote server i am able to see that in Gerrit Server.

Kindly guide if it is possible to have two way synchronization of git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only have it sync-ed in one direction - from **Gerrit** to **git**,
and this will not be a "true" sync, but simply a `pull` action in **git**, from **Gerrit**.

Technically, you can also do that the other way around,
i.e.: push a list of commits to **Gerrit** (from **git**) without a review,
but that defeats the whole purpose of Gerrit, so would not recommend it.

Also, see here a discussion about an attempt to sync **Gerrit** and **GitHub**:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/NwLEwlOiqoM